# fetch the count of records from table by setting the Maximum results in JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use JPA to fetch the count of records from table Customer by setting the Maximum results(10).

The expectation is,
    1. to receive only 10 as count If the count returned by query is greater than 10.
    2. to receive the exact number of transactions if the count is equal to or less than 10

I try to achieve in the below way.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Customer c where c.countryId ='Canada' and c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
query.setMaxResults(10);
long customerCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

But I am not getting the result as expected. When the query results is 100 ( I mean more than 10), then I could see 100 is being returned by the query.

Can anyone please advise me If something is incorrect in my approach?
OR
Is it not possible to achieve this in single query?
OR
Any other best way to achieve this?

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Your query always return 1 row because it's a count. It always returns a row with the number of customers that match the condition. query.setMaxResults(10); is used for setting the max row that the query execution could fetch.

Comment: I don't know why i get my answer usefulness, but do you tested it? i am sure it will work.

Comment: @mibrahim, yes I tried in the way I posted in my question to get count. It didnt work for count query. But If I use select query as given below Im able to retrieve only the maximum number of results                                                                                            TypedQuery q = em.createQuery("SELECT c.id FROM Customer c WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND c.lanuguage ='ENG'", Customer .class);
query.setMaxResults(10);                                                                                List<Customer> listCustomer = q.getResultSet();

Comment: @AlagammalP i updated my answer, please try code after update word and let me know what happen, and way there are not logic to use setMaxResults(10); with COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **COUNT** so why you are using max result ?

Your result will be always single result as it will be a number of Customers COUNT?

Your code should be next if you want to get the total count

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Customer c WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
long customerCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

**UPDATE**

> AND If you just want to get 10 as a maximum total count if COUNT result than
>   10 else you will got the real COUNT result, so please try next
>
> ```
> Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 10 THEN 10 ELSE COUNT(c) END FROM Customer c WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
> int customerCount = (Integer)query.getSingleResult();
> ```
>
> Or if you need it in logn type you can add **l** to number, for example 10l like in next query (**NOTE:** in next query **10l** is not **101** but 10 in long type)
>
> ```
> Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(c) > 10l THEN 10l ELSE COUNT(c) END FROM Customer c WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
> long customerCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
> ```

Anyway you can use maximum result if you want to get list of customer ids for example (assuming customer has id property with type Integer)

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c.id FROM Customer c WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
query.setMaxResults(10);
List<Integer> customersIds = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: The above approach results in  Exception Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: @AlagammalP will test Update my side and see that.

Comment: @AlagammalP i just tested my solution and it was have only one error which was about casting to long, because CASE return INTEGER for my query not Long, so just make the cast Integer will make it work, i will update the solution, any way this is different than your exception which means you have another problem your side, are you using this query inside another query ?

Comment: anyway i updated my solution to cast result to (Integer) instead of (Long), and it's working fine my side

Comment: @AlagammalP i updated my answer again to allow result in Long type too, and it's working fine my side as result in Integer

Comment: Same  ExceptionCaused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis even after appending the letter "l" to 10.

Comment: i am sure it's not related to answer, can u please post the whole method which have the code of this query ?

Comment: missing right parenthesis >> it seems there are a problem your side in opening and closing parenthesis somewhere in your code, it's not related to answer btw, this is different problem in your code, so please post the whole method for me if you can.