# JPA count query with maximum results

Tags: java, jpa

Can you please share me code snippet to be written via JPA in order to generate the below sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Customer c 
WHERE c.countryId ='Canada' AND 
      c.lanuguage ='ENG' AND 
      ROW_NUM <=10;
```

Because I tried in the below way. But MaxResults is not getting applied it seems as I can able to recieve the count more than 10.

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT COUNT(c) FROM Customer c where c.countryId ='Canada' and c.lanuguage ='ENG'");
query.setMaxResults(10);
long customerCount = (Long)query.getSingleResult();
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `ROW_NUM` is supposed to represent here.  Do you have a column called row number?  Even if your DB supports this, it isn't part of JPA, and anyway would require an ordering to make any sense.

Comment: might you just need to set  limit = 10 ?

Comment: The setting of max results only affects the number of rows you get as an end result. A select count will allways return only 1 row (containing the count that has been done). So the max results is applied but has no affect and is not what you can use for this case. But wouldn't it be the simplest solution just to get the total count like you currently do and return 10 if it is higher?

Comment: You ask the same question 2 days ago.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587842/fetch-the-count-of-records-from-table-by-setting-the-maximum-results-in-jpa     This was not helpful?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fetch the count of records from table by setting the Maximum results in JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42587842/fetch-the-count-of-records-from-table-by-setting-the-maximum-results-in-jpa)

Comment: @rvit34, Yes the idea is to set the max limit to 10

Comment: @AlagammalP just set it then, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp

Comment: @911DidBush, Yes that is also a simple logic. But my Idea is I want to control the query to read till 10 when the results is greater than 10 (For example 80,000 rows). I wonder why the method SetMaxResult is not working out here when it is working for normal select query in JPA?

Comment: @rvit34, setting top 10 rows to the query can be acheived by means of setMaxresults in JPA. But In my question I have mentioned that It is not working for count. But when it is a select it is working perfectly.

Comment: @AlagammalP, ok, I see. Probably `setMaxResults(10)` is apllied after sql query is executed (it is applied to count of rows in the result set). Since count returns only one row it's ignoned. But limit(or ROW_NUM) operator is applied inside of query. That's my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Select on count will always return a single value. If you want to have a count lower than 10, add HAVING.

```
SELECT COUNT(c) AS 
FROM Customer c
WHERE c.countryId='Canada' and c.language='END'
HAVING COUNT(c)<=10
```

Comment: What will be the result when row count is greater than 10.

Comment: As you use .getSingleResult(), it will raise a NoResultException. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getSingleResult--